# ElasticSearch explain query to know which fields are being accessed

Tags: elasticsearch, permissions, elasticsearch-dsl

I'm implementing a **permission system** for elastic search for our data scientists (accessing through a proxy microservice), to prevent certain users querying specific fields.

I've been looking through ES documentation to find if there was any opensource function that return all the fields that are accessed through a query but without luck.
Only XPACK is offering a solution, but from my understanding is not opensource and it would be crazy expensive for us.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/field-level-security.html

E.g.

```
{
  "from" : 1,
  "size" : 2,
  "query" : {
    "bool" : {
      "filter" : [
        {
          "bool" : {
            "must" : [
              {
                "nested" : {
                  "query" : {
                    "bool" : {
                      "must" : [
                        {
                          "term" : {
                            "nestedField.nestedAbc.fieldNotSupposedToAccess" : {
                              "value" : 0.102908,
                              "boost" : 1.0
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      ],
                      "adjust_pure_negative" : true,
                      "boost" : 1.0
                    }
                  },
                  "path" : "nestedField.nestedAbc",
                  "ignore_unmapped" : false,
                  "score_mode" : "none",
                  "boost" : 1.0
                }
              }
            ],
            "adjust_pure_negative" : true,
            "boost" : 1.0
          }
        }
      ],
      "adjust_pure_negative" : true,
      "boost" : 1.0
    }
  },
  "_source" : {
    "includes" : [
      "_doc"
    ],
    "excludes" : [ ]
  },
   "function_score": {
      "script_score": {
        "script": {
          "lang": "painless",
          "source": """
            int total = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < doc['goals'].length; ++i) {
              total += doc['goals'][i];
            }
            return total;
          """
        }
      }
    }
}
```

and I would like that I would get a list of all of the fields like this:

```
["nestedField.nestedAbc.fieldNotSupposedToAccess","_doc","goals"]
```

Any idea other than having to create a complex parser from scratch?

Comment: Since you're accessing ES through a proxy microservice and you don't want to use XPack Security for that, you could implement that field filtering in that microservice

Comment: @Val that custom complex parser from scratch is exactly what I would love to avoid :D

Comment: You could leverage [source filtering](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-fields.html#source-filtering) with `_source.excludes` as a poor man's "security"

Comment: That would only exclude returning the result, but would prevent them to have a `WHERE fieldNotSupposedToAccess=4`, correct?

Comment: There's no magic here, unfortunately.